# Understanding the behavior of a single ampersand operator (&) on integers

Tags: c#, operators, bitwise-operators

I understand that the single ampersand operator is normally used for a 'bitwise AND' operation. However, can anyone help explain the interesting results you get when you use it for comparison between two numbers?

For example;

```
(6 & 2) = 2
(10 & 5) = 0
(20 & 25) = 16
(123 & 20) = 16
```

I'm not seeing any logical link between these results and I can only find information on  comparing booleans or single bits.

Comment: Are you sure ( 20 & 25 ) == 4?

Comment: What you're seeing *is* the result of a "bitwise AND" operation. (Except for the `(20 & 25) = 4` bit, which I assume is a typo.)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Compare the binary representations of each of those.

```
    110 &     010 =     010
   1010 &    0101 =    0000
  10100 &   11001 =   10000
1111011 & 0010100 = 0010000
```

In each case, a digit is 1 in the result only when it is 1 on both the left AND right side of the input.

Comment: @Rekin: For small numbers like these I can convert between decimal, hex and binary in my head, pretty much.  I also found a corner to tuck most of the ASCII table into.

Comment: @Jefrrey, just out of curiosity - do You work in some low level environment? Such like, say, protocol, messaging or performance related software?

Comment: @Rekin: I deal with a lot of protocol related stuff, from bits on a serial port up through message queuing and XML web services, and often have to shoehorn all of it into Windows CE.

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert your numbers to binary representation and then you will see the link between results like 6 & 2= 2 is actually 110 & 010  =010 etc
10 & 5 is 1010 & 0101 = 0000

Answer (score 4):

The binary and operation is performed on the integers, represented in binary. For example

```
110  (6)
010  (2)
--------
010  (2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The bitwise AND is does exactly that: it does an AND operation on the Bits.

So to anticipate the result you need to look at the bits, not the numbers.

AND gives you 1, only if there's 1 in both number in the same position:

```
6(110) & 2(010) =  2(010)
10(1010) & 5(0101) = 0(0000)
```

A bitwise OR will give you 1 if there's 1 in either numbers in the same position:

```
6(110) | 2(010) =  6(110)
10(1010) | 5(0101) = 15(1111)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
6     = 0110
2     = 0010 
6 & 2 = 0010

20      = 10100
25      = 11001
20 & 25 = 10000
```

(looks like you're calculation is wrong for this one)

Etc...

Answer (score 2):

Internally, Integers are stored in [binary format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system). I strongly suggest you read about that. Knowing about the bitwise representation of numbers is very important.

That being said, the bitwise comparison compares the bits of the parameters:

```
Decimal: 6    &    2 = 2
Binary:  0110 & 0010 = 0010
```

Answer (score 0):

Bitwize AND matches the bits in binary notation one by one and the result is the bits that are comon between the two numbers.

To convert a number to binary you need to understand the binary system.

For example
6 = 110 binary

The 110 represents 1x4 + 1x2 + 0x1 = 6.

2 then is
0x4 + 1x2 + 0x1 = 2.

Bitwize and only retains the positions where both numbers have the position set, in this case the bit for 2 and the result is then 2.

Every extra bit is double the last so a 4 bit number uses the multipliers 8, 4, 2, 1 and can there fore represent all numbers from 0 to 15 (the sum of the multipliers.)