# What does &= in this code mean?

Tags: c#, pointers

I don't understand `*p++ &= 0xFF;` in the following code. Why does the operator `&=` appear here?

```
unsafe void Foo(int[,] arr)
{
    int length = arr.Length;
    fixed (int* b = arr)
    {
        int* p = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         *p++ &= 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just another assignment operator, like +=, but for &. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691314(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: dereferencing p, incrementing p, anding with FF(256) and assigning this result back to p. Compiler output shoud be same with readable form of `p[i]=p[i]&256;`

Comment: It is the `AND` [bitwise operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-assignment-operator

Comment: The variable type is int which is four bytes.  So the code is moving four bytes (p++) and only keeping the least significant byte by ANDing the integer with 0xFF.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik and assigning the result back to where p used to point

Comment: @pm100 you are right. Where it points. Otherwise would be disasterous. But it is easily corrected with `p[i]=p[i]&256;` which comes afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an another **[`assignment operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-assignment-operator)**

**`x &= y`**

is

```
x = x & y
```

In this case, you are incrementing p adding with FF and assigning to p

Comment: is it atomic by default?

Comment: assigning to *p, actually *(original p)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik No, it's not guaranteed to be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

So you've probably seen something like `a += b //a = a + b`.

This is essentially the same thing just with a bitwise comparison operator `&`. Specifically, the user here is getting the inverse binary value for p (I THINK, someone correct me please) in the form of 2's compliment.

See here for a good example of bitwise comparison, first answer: [Understanding the behavior of a single ampersand operator (&) on integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757447/understanding-the-behavior-of-a-single-ampersand-operator-on-integers)

Comment: the result is stored in *p not p

Answer (score 1):

It performs bitwise and operation to each element of the array.

For example, if p[i] = 256, it will become 0; if p[i] = -1, it will become 255; if p[i] = -2, it will become 254.

```
 256: 00000001 0000000
0xFF: 00000000 1111111
======================
   0: 00000000 0000000

  -1: 11111111 1111111
0xFF: 00000000 1111111
======================
 255: 00000000 1111111

  -2: 11111111 1111110
0xFF: 00000000 1111111
======================
 254: 00000000 1111110
```

Answer (score 1):

It will round all array contents to be in range [0,255] by performing AND bitwise operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
// for example: we are passing array with 4 elements (arr[2,2])

unsafe static void Foo (int[,] arr)
{
    int length = arr.Length; // length == 4

    fixed (int* b = arr) // b is a pointer to the first element of the 'arr' array (pointer is of type int)
    {
        int* p = b; // lets copy pointer to a new variable (we will change that variable in a loop)
                    // we cannot change 'b', because it is a 'fixed' variable

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // iterate over all 'arr' elements (4 elements)
            *p++ &= 0xFF; // *p = *p & 255   - it means we will use only 8 low bits from 32 bit int, all 'arr' values stay between [0..255]
                          // p = p + 4 (because int is 4 bytes)
                          // now p is a pointer to the second element in the 'arr' (each element in the arr is of size 4 bytes)

        // *p =   10101101 10101101 10101101 10101101
        // & 255  00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111
        // =      00000000 00000000 00000000 10101101
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They get the least significant bytes from each item in the array
*p++ gets the value pointed by p and set p to the next address
the value obtained is a 32 bit integer

lhs &= rhs is equivalent to lhs = lhs & rhs;

0xFFFF - 32 bits
0xFF   - 16 bits

0xFFFF & 0xFF  == 0xFFFF & 0x00FF

X & 0 is 0 so they are converting the first 16 bits to zero getting only the least significant bits