# 16-bit to 10-bit conversion code explanation

Tags: c++, accelerometer

I came across the following code to convert 16-bit numbers to 10-bit numbers and store it inside an integer. Could anyone maybe explain to me what exactly is happening with the AND 0x03?

```
// Convert the data to 10-bits    
    int xAccl = (((data[1] & 0x03) * 256) + data[0]);    
    if(xAccl > 511) {    
      xAccl -= 1024;  
    }
```

Link to where I got the code: https://www.instructables.com/id/Measurement-of-Acceleration-Using-ADXL345-and-Ardu/

Comment: Take a random 16-bit value, and do the operations one by one *on paper*. See what you get at each step of the way.

Comment: `data[1] & 0x03` means to take the number in `data` at index 1 and compare the binary representation of it to the binary representation of the `0x03` (this is hex). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757447/understanding-the-behavior-of-a-single-ampersand-operator-on-integers) for how the `&` comparison works.

Comment: Also please don't spam with unrelated language tags. Judging from the context of the link its code from an Arduino project, which means it's C++.

Comment: Sorry about that, its code taken from an Arduino project yes, but my code is written in a combination of C, C++ and C# for the different aspects of the project, but will definitely keep that in mind, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise operator `&` will make a mask, so in this case, it voids the 6 highest bits of the integer.

Basically, this code does a modulo `% 1024` (for unsigned values).

Comment: Oh, the solution is so simple, for some reason I just did not get it, thank!

Comment: This is not quite a modulo operation, because it result is n the [-512,511] range.

Comment: Hence the comment in the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

`data[1]` takes the 2nd byte; `& 0x03` masks that byte with binary `11` - so: takes 2 bits; `* 256` is the same as `<< 8` - i.e. pushes those 2 bits into the 9th and 10th positions; adding `data[0]` to data combines these two bytes (personally I'd have used `|`, not `+`).

So; `xAccl` is now the first 10 bits, using big-endian ordering.

The `> 511` seems to be a sign check; essentially, it is saying "if the 10th bit is set, treat the entire thing as a negative integer as though we'd used 10-bit twos complement rules".

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, really appreciate it. Was wondering about the + myself, but might just edit that to |. Thank you!